# How to make default expand level for OBIEE Parent Child Hierarchy

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

I currently have a parent-child hierarchy in OBIEE model. Everytime I open a analysis with the model containing that hierarchy it only loads the top level data of the hierarchy, then I need to expand each level by clicking the + button next to it and it takes lot of time to expand each node.Is there a way in OBIEE to set default level up to which the hierarchy needs to expand when I load the report/analysis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hierarchy itself is created in order to view reports in a **Hierarchical** structure. Meaning I navigate from Year >> Quarter >> Month >> Day.

So what you are asking for is not possible in OBIEE (Columns with hierarchies).